# How to convert integer to base58?

Tags: python, base58

I have a decimal number, and I want to show it on the screen as a base58 string. There is what I have already:

```
>>> from base58 import b58encode
>>> b58encode('33')
'4tz'
```

This appears to be correct, but since the number is less than 58, shouldn't the resulting base58 string be only one character? I must be missing some step. I think it's because I'm passing in the string '33' not actually the number 33.

When I pass in a straight integer, I get an error:

```
>>> b58encode(33)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required (also str), not 'int'
```

Basically I want to encode a number in base58 so that it uses the least amount of characters as possible...

Comment: What result are you expecting, exactly?

Comment: I expect the number 33 to be expressed as a single digit when converted to base58. Is this assumption incorrect? A number less than 58^2 should be expressed as two characters, a number less than 58^6 should be less than 6 chars, etc... In my example, I get a 3 digit result for a number less than 58...

Comment: And what happens when you do it for an `int` and not a `str`?

Comment: b58encode doesn't take an integer, the error says: a bytes-like object is required (also str), not 'int'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`base58.b58encode` expects bytes or a string, so convert 33 to bytes then encode:

```
>>> base58.b58encode(33)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required (also str), not 'int'
>>> i = 33
>>> bs = i.to_bytes(1, sys.byteorder)
>>> bs
b'!'
>>> base58.b58encode(bs)
b'a'
```

Answer (score 3):

For Python, you can now use `b58encode_int`

```
>>> import base58
>>> base58.b58encode_int(33)
b'a'
```